# Get samples from a known log density

Tags: sampling, numerics

I have two distributions $p_a$ and $p_b$ and I want to **sample** from $p_c$, defined via
the log density

$$
\log p_c(x) = (1+w) \log p_a(x) - w \log p_b(x)
$$

or via the desnity

$$
p_c(x) = \frac{ p_a(x)^{1+w} }{p_b(x)^w}
$$

I am a noob when it comes to sampling from a distribution, so any pointers would be welcome. Is this tractable in general, or do I need to make assumptions about $p_a$ and $p_b$? For example, for some contexts, both could be multi variate gaussians, by searching around did not lead to any obvious ways on how this simplifies things.

Also, I can sample from both $p_a$ and $p_b$ already, is there a formalism that allows me to translate those samples to a sample from $p_c$?

Comment: How would you sample from $p_a(x)$ and  $p_b(x)$? Are these densities or CDFs? If they are densities, how do you know $p_c(x)$ is a density?

Comment: @Henry At the moment, $p_a$ and $p_b$ are multivariate gaussians, and I'm using tensorflow probability to obtain samples from them. I am actually not sure if $p_c$ is a density, but it's definitly proportional to one.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean $(1- w) p_a + w p_b)$, i.e. a smooth transition between the two log-densities, because what you wrote is kind of weird and asymmetrical?

Comment: Also I think @Henry is pointing out that it is not obvious and perhaps not true, that $\int p_c < \infty$

Comment: @LukasLohse no I want to sample from the extrapolation formula.

Comment: We can assume both distributions have similar means and p_b probably has higher variance than p_a, so overall I think it's a safe ratio.

Comment: For the one dimensional case the relevant property seems to be that $w 1/\sigma_b^2 - (1+w) 1/\sigma_a^2 < 0$, so you do seem to have a safe case as long as $w \geq 0$!, but if $\sigma_b < \sigma_a$ there are many cases where $p_c$ is no likelihood at all.

Answer (score 1):

Since $p_c$ is a potentially unnormalized density, but I can write down a closed form term for it (because I know $p_a$ and $p_b$), I just implemented rejection sampling and this seems to work as intended.